# Echo index of array before \t

Tags: php, arrays

I have a txt file of trivia questions. I have split them into 2 array indexes and are seperated with a \t. I need to print those questions to the user in order and I don't know how to display part of the array index before the first \t.

```
<?php
session_start();
$file = "trivQuestions.txt";
$result = file($file);
$_SESSION['question'] = array();
$_SESSION['correctAnswers'] = array();

var_dump($_SESSION['question']);
foreach ( $result as $content ) {

$question =  explode("\t", $content);
//    echo $question[0];
//echos all questions
var_dump($question[0]);
//echo $question[0];
//echos all answers
//echo $question[1];

}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){


}else{
echo "Welcome to trivia! Enter your answer below.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you get an error? What is your input? What should your output be? Do you mean literal `\t` or a tab?

Comment: @ishegg I don't get an error. The user has to input the answer but I need to show them the first question in the txt file. When I var_dump the question[0] if shows all the questions on new lines, for example this is one 
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'In which movie does Michael J. Fox play a time-travelling teenager?' (length=67)
and there are 4 more after that. I need it to show the first question and when the user hits submit go to the next one and so on

Comment: Oh, well that's not what you're question suggests at all. Your code is working fine, but you want to separate the questions into different pages. You should edit the Q to make it clearer.

Comment: Can you show us some content from your question file, so we know what exactly we are working here with? This would help to analyze your problem far better and may lead to an answer that helps you.

Comment: @natheriel 17 Each question and answer is seperated by a tab and each question with the answer is on a new line.     In which movie does Michael J. Fox play a time-travelling teenager? Back to the Future
In 'Old School', what song does Frank try and sing at Blue's funeral. Dust In The Wind
What hiphop heroes joined forces with Aerosmith for a new version of Walk This Way? Run DMC

Answer (score 0):

As your file has a question and answer separated by a tab on each new line in the file, you will have to split your file by each new line first. After that you will be able to loop trough each line of the file and split it by a tab.

From here you could add you split into a new array or do whatever you want to do with it.

In the code below I tried to demonstrate how such a split with loop would work, according to your description.

```
$file = "trivQuestions.txt";
$result = file($file);

// before you split by \t, you have to split by each new line.
// this will get you an array with each question + answer as one value
// PHP_EOL stands for end of line. PHP tries to get the end of line by using the systems default one. you can adjust that, if it a specific
// linebreak like "\n" or something else you know of. 
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $result);
// var_dump($lines); <- with this you would see that you are on the right way

// setup a questions array to fill it up later
$questions = array();

// lets loop trough the lines
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    // now you can explode on tab
    $entry = explode("\t", $line);
    // according to you description the question comes first, the answer later split by tab
    // so we fill the questions array
    $questions[] = $entry[0]; // the 0 element will be the question. if you want to adress the answer, use $entry[1]. maybe you want to add this in an other array for checks? 

}

// this will give you the first question
var_dump($questions[0]);
```

If I have missed something or misunderstood parts of your question, let me know. Maybe I can adjust this code, to make it work as you need it to be.